# Can I generate superscipt in iText using input only?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm involved in a project where we generate pdf-files using iText. I want to generate superscipt text and I know that methods exists for converting chunks of text to superscript however, I am in a situation where it is desirable to decide based on the input whether or not a piece of text should be superscript or not. An optimal solution would be something like: `2<superscript>nd</superscript>` to generate the text "2<sup>nd</sup>".

Is this, or anything like this possible?

It is worth noting that I do not write code directly against iText, there are layers between. This is why I need to decide what is superscript and not based on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the code that's using iText, then no, there's no way. iText doesn't parse the text you put in a `Chunk`.

In order to get a similar behaviour to what you want to achieve, you would need to do HTML to PDF conversion, with iText's companion [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/) for example.

Comment: What about unicode characters? Can they be inserted to display a specific character as superscript? Or is it the same situation here?

Answer (score 1):

When you find a `<superscript>` tag you can simply create a Chunk with correct properties:

```
public Chunk addSuperscript(String text) {
  float leading = determineCurrentLeading();
  Font f = determineCurrentFont();
  Font supFont = new Font(f);
  supFont.setSize(f.getSize() / 2f);
  Chunk c = new Chunk(text, supFont);
  c.setTextRise(leading / 2f);
  return c;
}
```

Then the chunk will be added to a Paragraph, a PdfPCell,... Depending on your implementation, you can determine the current leading and font used.

Hope this will help you.